# Eliminar elemento vacío de una lista

Tags: python-3.x, lista

Tengo un problemita... Tengo esta lista de listas:

```
[]
['Shanar', "Ab'Dendriel", '580 gp']
['Memech', 'Ankrahmun', '580 gp']
['Cornelia', 'Carlin', '580 gp']
```

Y quiero eliminar el primer elemento vacío `[]`, es decir, el par de corchetes vacío. Ya intenté con `.pop()` pero no me deja hacerlo, aparece el siguiente mensaje de error:

> IndexError: pop from empty list

Tampoco me permite con `.remove()`:

> ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Ya no se que hacer. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partiendo de una lista de listas como:

```
lista = [[],
         ['Shanar', "Ab'Dendriel", '580 gp'],
         ['Memech', 'Ankrahmun', '580 gp'],
         ['Cornelia', 'Carlin', '580 gp']]
```

Si sabes la posición de la sublista vacía en la lista, tienes varias posibilidades.

### Usar `del` sobre el item (indizando)

```
del lista[0]
```

Es la forma recomendable en éste caso. Pongo las dos siguientes porque mencionas que intentas usarlas, para que puedas ver como se deben utilizar en éste caso.

---

### Usar `list.remove`

```
lista.remove([])
```

A `list.remove` se le pasa el item a eliminar (realmente una referencia al mismo objeto de la lista u otro objeto que sea igual a él (`==`)), no se le pasa un índice. Aunque podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
lista.remove(lista[0])
```

pero `del` es más simple y más eficiente.

Ten en cuenta que **solo elimina el primer objeto que encuentra**, si hay más los deja, si no existe lanza una excepción `ValueError`.

---

### Usando `list.pop`

```
lista.pop(0)
```

A igual que del se  debe usar el índice del elemento a usar. Además de eliminar el item de la lista lo retorna. Observa que no se llama al método pop de la sublista, como sospecho que haces por el error que dices tener.

---

Si la lista puede o no tener una sublista vacía, pero de tenerla, la tiene siempre en la primera posición, puedes usar un condicional:

```
if not lista[0]:
    del lista[0]
```

Si no tienes idea de dónde está o si hay varias, tienes dos posibilidades:

### Generar una nueva lista filtrando las sublistas vacías

`Lista por compresión`

```
nueva_lista = [sublista for sublista in lista if sublista]
```

`Enfoque funcional con filter()`

```
nueva_lista = list(filter(bool, lista))
```

Se asume que tu lista es homogénea (tal como muestras), es decir, que solo contiene listas. Si no fuera así, éste enfoque eliminaría también todo lo que sea evaluado como False, tupla vacías, diccionarios vacios, 0, 0.0, cadenas vacías, etc.

Si tu lista fuera mixta, como `[[2], {}, [], "Hola", "", 0]` y solo quieraas eliminar las listas vacías, puedes usar la sintaxis que propone @Adrian Fusco en su respuesta o usar `isinstance`, más complicado, pero útil en casos de querer tener en cuenta la herencia:

```
nueva_lista = [item for item in lista if not (isinstance(item, list) and not item)]
```

### Remover sublistas vacías in-place

En éste caso podemos recurrir de nuevo a `del` y un ciclo, pero hay que tener cuidado en no invalidar el rango de índices, una técnica común es iterar en orden inverso:

```
for i in range(len(lista)-1, -1, -1):
     if not lista[i]:
         del lista[i]
```

Answer (score 2):

Nick:

Podrías comprobar la lista elemento por elemento de la siguiente forma:

```
from pprint import pprint

primera_lista = [[], [1,2,3], [], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
segunda_lista = [elemento_lista for elemento_lista in primera_lista if elemento_lista != []]

pprint(segunda_lista)
```

De esta forma verificas si el elemento no es una lista con la condición ( != [] ).
El resultado sería:

```
$ -> python3 List.py 
[[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

Comment: Hola Adrián, una observación, `if elemento_lista != []` no la forma correcta por convención  ni por eficiencia de comprobar si una lista está vacía (en tu ejemplo generas 4 objetos nuevos en memoria que no sirven para nada y que el GC debe recolectar luego), debe ser simplemente `[elemento_lista for elemento_lista in primera_lista if elemento_lista]`. Saludos.

Comment: Hola FJSevilla. Sí, es una forma básica y antigua de hacerlo pero para experiencia básica en Python creo que es la mejor forma de hacerlo. Y sí, efectivamente son objetos en memoria que no se utilizan para nada, y peor si la lista es mucho más grande. Hay otras opciones para utilizar como filter(), pero creo que para usuarios con experiencia básica sería lo más recomendable. Saludos y gracias por la observación.

Comment: Más explícito si que es, aunque pueda no ser la forma generalmente aceptada, si que es cierto que es útil en caso de querer comprobar si el objeto es una lista vacía y no otro objeto que se evalúe como falso. Aplicado a ésta pregunta, si la lista fuera heterogénea y solo quisiéramos eliminar listas vacías pero no diccionarios, tuplas cadenas, etc usar != [] es una forma simple de resolverlo. Por cierto, bienvenido a [es.so].

Comment: Gracias FJSevilla.

Answer (score 0):

En el caso de querer eliminar la lista por completo, se usa la palabra reservada del, de esta manera:

del lista_a_eliminar

solo usando esta linea de codigo se puede eliminar la lista. al ejecutar el comando 'del' la variable eliminada deja de existir y si quieres volver a usarla, deberas declararla nuevamente.

Comment: hey amigo, gracias por tu buena intención, sin embargo no resuelve mi problema. No necesito eliminar la lista como tal. Lo que necesito es eliminar una lista vacía dentro de otra lista:

`[]
['Shanar', "Ab'Dendriel", '580 gp']
['Memech', 'Ankrahmun', '580 gp']
['Cornelia', 'Carlin', '580 gp']`

Para este caso `[]` el par de corchetes en primera posición.